# Atlassian JIRA Plugin Development: How to make variables available to velocity templates

Tags: java, velocity, jira, webwork

**FAIR WARNING: this question is going to be pretty tough to answer unless you have experience with JIRA and have access to their source (enterprise users).**

Greetings all,

I am writing a plugin which extends AbstractIssueSelectAction.  I noticed that `${issue.summary}`, etc are all available from within my velocity template, however, there are other things I wish to expose.  I can't figure out how to add other things to the velocity parameter map.  I even used a remote debugger to try to step through the stack and figure out what is going on - but it was pretty unclear to me both due to a deep stack and the fact that I wasn't able to correctly attach all of the source (and lots of the webwork stuff seems to be obfuscated).

I have posted this question on the Atlassian support forums also, I am just cross-posting here to get more eyes on the problem.

Example action code:

```
public class MyOperation extends AbstractIssueSelectAction {

    // ...
    private final Issue myIssue;

    public String doCollect() throws Exception {
      log.debug("Running doCollect()");
      return "collectinfo";
    }
 }
```

Example plugin config:

```
  <webwork1 key="unique_key" name="My Name" class="java.lang.Object">
   <actions>
    <action name="com.mycompany.jira.extensions.MyOperation" alias="MyOperation">
     <view name="collectinfo">/templates/myoperation-collectinfo.vm</view>
     <view name="success">/templates/myoperation-success.vm</view>
    </action>
   </actions>
  </webwork1>
```

In the velocity template, `${issue.summary}` correctly resolves to the current issue's summary, but if myIssue was some other issue, for example, I want to be able to use `${myIssue.summary}`.

Thanks!
-Carl

Comment: Note:  This question was about jira 3.X-4.X and probably no longer applies to jira 5.X+, it is no longer common to extend Abstract classes like AbstractIssueSelectAction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using $action.mymethod() to get at the information, where mymethod is a method you define in the Action class "MyOperation"? The velocity parameters are fiddly to find out how they get populated.

~Matt

Comment: Matt,

I figured ou thte problem.  Embarrassingly, my getters were returning null because they didn't get initialized, my init() function was only being run later.  Unfortunately, JIRA swallowed the NPEs like the whore it is, so I was only able to tell after trying your suggestion - calling ${action.myMethod()} exposed the NPEs.  Thanks Matt!