# Need some help with velocity templates for Jira Plugins

Tags: java, velocity, jira

I am trying to develop a plugin for jira and ive having quite a lot of trouble as i have little knowlwdge of how it works.

I have a plugin that:
adds a button to the options menu in the view issue screen
adds a tab in the same screen
loads a /secure/action!map.jspa page from a success.vm file.

I would like to be able to load fields into this page like a version picker and a custom field myField

how do I go about accessing the built in fields?

i had a look at this post but it went over my head so some dumbing down would be much appreicated [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507241/atlassian-jira-plugin-development-how-to-make-variables-available-to-velocity-te)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex,

The [WebWork tutorial plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/17189) that I wrote for JIRA might help with the background of how it all works. Also, a crisp and clear description of exactly what you want JIRA to do. And then if you get really fed up, [hire a consultant](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/APW/Partner+Wiki+Home) to do it for you. Disclosure: I'm in the list of consultants as "[Consulting Toolsmiths](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/APW/Consulting+Toolsmiths)".

~Matt

Comment: thanks, that plugin's what I was after, suitably basic! 

I'm trying to build a plugin to slot into my bug page that can be used for root cause analysis. So my idea is that you go to the more actions menu and select RCA. You should then be presented with a questionnaire that will (probably) display relevant questions based on previous answers to try and pigeon hole the root problem. You then submit this form and the results are displayed in a RCA tab and the more Actions menu will no longer have any RCA option.

Sorry i cant mark your question as helpful (im not cool enough!)